# Can I run pyspark locally without installing spark on windows 10?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, windows-10

I need to create a proof of concept using pyspark and I was wondering if there is a way to install it and use it via pip without having to install and configure spark itself. I've read a few answers suggesting that the newer versions of pyspark allow you to run it in standalone mode without without needing the full spark but when I try that I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\320181940\PycharmProjects\meetup\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext("local", "meetup_etl")
  File "C:\Users\320181940\PycharmProjects\meetup\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 144, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\320181940\PycharmProjects\meetup\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 331, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\320181940\PycharmProjects\meetup\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 101, in launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, **popen_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I installed pyspark 3.1.3 using pip, and I'm trying to run this on Windows 10. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need Java and Spark and configure it to be able to run your pyspark code.  If you want to try pyspark code and not want to set it up, you can try databricks community edition online.  https://community.cloud.databricks.com/login.html

Answer (score 1):

Since Apache Spark runs on Java virtual machines, it can run on any operating system as long as Java is installed.

PySpark requires Java 8 or later. `java` should be in your %PATH% (check with `java -version`), and the variable `JAVA_HOME` (`%JAVA_HOME%`) should be set to your Java installation.

From the [official site](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/):

> *Spark runs on both Windows and UNIX-like systems (e.g. Linux, Mac OS), and it should run on any platform that runs a supported version of Java. This should include JVMs on x86_64 and ARM64. It’s easy to run locally on one machine — all you need is to have java installed on your system PATH, or the JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to a Java installation.*

There's two ways of getting pyspark:

- [install `pyspark` with `pip` (or `conda`)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html)
- [install Spark](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and use the `pyspark` client that comes with it

The `pyspark` that gets installed with `pip`/`conda` comes with its own Spark engine.

And conversely Spark comes with an own `pyspark`.

For a proof of concept it's a good idea to just install `pyspark` and use the built-in Spark engine. Installing Spark can give more flexibility with the Spark engine configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install java and add JAVA_HOME to your environment variables path

Comment: @An Amir Hossein Shahdaei I tried that, restarted my IDE and got the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Start a python interpreter, create a spark session and run your code, here's an example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [["I'm ready!"], ["If I could put into words how much I love waking up at 6 am on Mondays I would."]]).toDF(
        "text")
df.show()
```

Also make sure to set up HADOOP_HOME like it's specified in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/d4rkc0de/0fe1307fc70178398a9d55c0fb2c91df)